# Detect changes to localstorage with Vue and Apollo

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apollo, apollo-client

I have a Vue app that uses Apollo to make GraphQL queries and mutations. The Apollo client is set up like so:

```
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({ uri: '/graphql' });
networkInterface.use([{
  applyMiddleware(req, next) {
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      req.options.headers = {};  // Create the header object if needed.
    }
    req.options.headers['authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('token') ? localStorage.getItem('token') : null;
    next();
  }
}]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface,
});
```

When i log into my API and get the access token I have to refresh the page for the Apollo client to recognize that a token now exists in localStorage. Why doesn't apollo detect the token in localStorage?

Comment: The code looks fine. After you logged in and perform a request to the server via Apollo the request should contain a authorization token.

Where is the problem?

Comment: I'm using an external module to fetch the token, and I can confirm that the token is in localStorage. The problem is that I have to refresh the page for Vue/Apollo to recognize that there is a token present in localStorage.

Comment: The localStorage is a storage in the browser and it is not related to Vue/Apollo.
So you might want to check if there are some race conditions with your external module. Meaning that the module is not finished with retrieving the token and apollo is already performing the request

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've been trying to delay calling Apollo with setTimeout, but still no luck. I got it working with location.reload(), but I don't know if this is the recommended solution for this or maybe I'm handling all of all wrong.